# Change Button label/text when pushed

Tags: swift, button

So I have a `@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {}`
with a label that says "hey" from the beginning.

How do I change that text when I click the button?
Can't find any **swift-related** answers that work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    (sender as! UIButton).setTitle("newTitle", for: [])
}
```

Or just:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.setTitle("newTitle", for: [])
}
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you, Moe! Works great, gonna need to learn that syntax and what is happening but that I can google :)

Comment: You're welcome! You're just using the `sender` which is your button, and calling a method called `setTitle` passing to it the new name and telling it that this new name will applied for the title in *normal* state by saying `for: []`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the text in the label in that function:

```
label.text = "Hello"
```